# IOS build contains symbols visible in IDA

Tags: c++, ios, arm, decompiling, ida

We are using C++ on a IOS project and Apple llvm 3 compiler for ARM architecture. I have noticed that IDA can open the ARM exe file and in the exports tab i found virtual table constructors for lots of c++ code (something like `construction vtable for'BaseClass-in-OtherClass 00AB6AC5' where BaseClass and OtherClass are actual c++ classes) and from there you can find addresses for other subroutines.

I'm unfamiliar with IDA but i think that from there you can find sensitive subroutines and change them for other purposes. I would like to know how all the symbol names made it into the release build ( we are missing a compiler switch? ) and if this stuff can indeed be used to easily track down routines that work with sensitive information.

Is there a way to remove all the names from the build?

Thanks,
Raxvan.

Answer (score 2):

`strip -x Myapp.app/Contents/MacOS/Myapp` should remove all symbols not required for running the program. (There is probably some XCode setting for this too.) You may need to play with [visibility options](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility) to make sure all private symbols are marked properly.

Note that you won't be able to remove the Objective-C names (classes, fields and methods), as they're encoded in the Objective-C metadata structures in the data segment of the program and are required by the Objective-C runtime.

Another source of symbolic information is C++ RTTI (Run-time Type Information). IDA currently does not use it but it's possible to recover class names with some additional scripts. You can turn off RTTI generation with `-fno-rtti` but this will break your code if you use `dynamic_cast<>` or `typeid` operators.

Comment: Thiank, we have little objective-c code , the main concern is c++ , and strip doesn't remove them, also we removed all compiler options that we think could generate symbols and still no luck. RTTI is off.

Comment: Try `-fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden`.